# My npm module seems to be partially disappearing after a while

Tags: npm

I have tried over and over and over to find a solution, but I seriously can not understand what is going on.

```
$ npm -v
6.5.0
$ node -v
v10.10.0
```

My `package.json` pulls in the followin dependencies:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "tests": "phpunit --testdox"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "laravel-mix": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "purifycss-webpack": "^0.7.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^0.7.2",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bugsnag/js": "^5.1.0",
    "@bugsnag/plugin-vue": "^5.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.10.0",
    "clientjs": "^0.1.11",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "glob-all": "^3.1.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.4.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.6.9",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.0",
    "purify-css": "^1.2.6",
    "pusher-js": "^4.3.1",
    "qs": "^6.6.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.1.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.3.2",
    "vue-router": "^2.8.1",
    "vue-wysiwyg": "^1.7.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

I can do an `npm run dev` 'x' times without any issue, when all of a sudden, without ever having ran another npm command, or pulled in new dependencies, or whatever, it can all of a sudden complain about a missing modules.

```
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'es-to-primitive/es6'
```

This is just an example; it has been other modules as well.
My solution to this is basically:

```
$ rm -f -R ./node_modules/*
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

This *always* fixes the issue.  I just don't understand why.  The dependency should have been installed prior because my previous builds ran just fine.  I'm running on a Macbook Pro, and I seriously have no idea what might be causing this behaviour.

On my last run, I checked `node_modules/es-to-primitive` and there was no es6.js file, so I understand the error, but after doing the above fix, it got that file installed.  I guess I just don't understand how it can 'disappear' again after a while...

Anything I'm doing wrong or don't understand properly?

Thanks!

Comment: It's because different modules can install packages on the fly (babel, laravel-mix, ect...)  Example, laravel-mix optionally install node-sass if you use the sass feature, etc..  Do you have this problem using node8?   Due to deprecation of illegal internal method usage in node10, there are many breaking changes out there between the two Node versions for modules including: laravel-mix, babel, webpack, etc...

Comment: I understand that, but if you run your build x times without changing any dependencies, and then all of a sudden it stops building, I don’t understand; these builds that succeeded must have had the modules available at that time, no?  I don’t know for sure it is because of an upgrade to node10, but it may very well be...  although I still don’t understand why one time it fails and the next it runs fine to fail again after that.  There’s no pattern... :(

Comment: Did you also remove package-lock.json after deleting node_modules?  Package may also lock modules in older npm and is locally cached.

Comment: The .lock file is used for production builds, not?  But again: after doing npm install, it’s always fixed, so even the .lock doesn’t matter...

Comment: No package-lock.json is use to make sure the right package version is always installed.  This help sync/make sure all developers on the Team is using the same package.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn’t impact me...  after npm install, no matter whether the lock file is there or not, the issue is always resolved...

Answer (score 2):

I hope I am not too late, but I had the exact same problem and it was driving me absolutely insane. I had to delete the `node_modules` directory and reinstall everything up to several times a day, and nothing I did made any difference. It then crossed my mind that iCloud Drive syncing may be causing the problem, as I had my project directory saved in `~/Documents`. I tried to delete the directory from iCloud Drive and let it completely sync, and it made it somewhat better but there still were issues with some of the modules. I asked myself, there must be a way to exclude a directory from syncing? And yes, it is!

Apparently, adding `.nosync` to the name of a file or directory will exclude it from syncing to iCloud Drive. Earlier you could add a blank file named `.nosync` to any directory to exclude it, but it seems this no longer works, at least not for me on macOS 10.15.2.

With that said, I am very happy to share that renaming the `node_modules` directory to `node_modules.nosync`, and adding a link to the new directory to keep npm from complaining, seems to have solved the issue:

```sh
$ mv node_modules node_modules.nosync/ && ln -s node_modules.nosync node_modules
```

After doing this, I have not had to delete and reinstall the modules even once! Everything just works, just as it should.